# Azure Django deployment failure

Tags: python, django, azure, deployment

I am trying to deploy a Django web app to Azure app service.
I have set up the continuous deployment with a Github repo for the project.

The project is functuioning locally.
The deployment is failing with the following logs:

```
Command: deploy.cmd
Handling python deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'web.2.7.config'
Detected requirements.txt.
Creating  virtual environment.
The system cannot find the path specified.
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.\r\nThe system cannot find the path specified.\r\nD:\Program Files(x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\61.60316.2745\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd deploy.cmd
```

I have included the following deployment files at the project root level:

```
.deployment, 
deploy.cmd, 
ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py, 
requiremnts.txt, 
web.2.7.config
```

I tried deploying the project from a local git repo. Which returned the following logs:

```
git push azure
Counting objects: 198, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (118/118), done.
Writing objects: 100% (198/198), 47.36 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 198 (delta 94), reused 120 (delta 65)
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id 'a68e71809f'.
remote: Running custom deployment command...
remote: Running deployment command...
remote: Handling python deployment.
remote: KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
remote: Copying file: '.gitignore'
remote: Copying file: 'db.sqlite3'
remote: Copying file: 'manage.py'
remote: Copying file: 'ptvs_virtualenv_proxy.py'
remote: Copying file: 'requirements.txt'
remote: Copying file: 'web.2.7.config'
remote: Copying file: 'accounts\admin.py'
remote: Copying file: 'accounts\apps.py'
remote: Copying file: 'accounts\backends.py'
remote: Copying file: 'accounts\forms.py'
remote: Copying file: 'accounts\models.py'
remote: Copying file: 'accounts\tests.py'
remote: Copying file: 'accounts\views.py'
remote: Copying file: 'accounts\__init__.py'
remote: Copying file: 'accounts\migrations\0001_initial.py'
remote: Copying file: 'accounts\migrations\__init__.py'
remote: Copying file: 'isi_django\settings.py'
remote: Copying file: 'isi_django\urls.py'
remote: Copying file: 'isi_django\wsgi.py'
remote: Copying file: 'isi_django\__init__.py'
remote: Copying file: 'isi_hours\admin.py'
remote: The system cannot find the path specified.
remote: Copying file: 'isi_hours\apps.py'
remote: The system cannot find the path specified.
remote: Copying file: 'isi_hours\forms.py'
remote: Copying file: 'isi_hours\models.py'
remote: Copying file: 'isi_hours\tests.py'
remote: Copying file: 'isi_hours\views.py'
remote: Copying file: 'isi_hours\__init__.py'
remote: Copying file: 'isi_hours\migrations\__init__.py'
remote: Copying file: 'static\css\home.css'
remote: Copying file: 'templates\base.html'
remote: Copying file: 'templates\datepicker.html'
remote: Copying file: 'templates\employee.html'
remote: Copying file: 'templates\empreport.html'
remote: Copying file: 'templates\home.html'
remote: Copying file: 'templates\index.html'
remote: Copying file: 'templates\login.html'
remote: Copying file: 'templates\logout.html'
remote: Copying file: 'templates\project.html'
remote: Copying file: 'templates\projreport.html'
remote: Copying file: 'templates\register.html'
remote: Detected requirements.txt.
remote: Creating  virtual environment.
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote:
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
To https://isireporting.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/isireporting.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Is this resulting from the deployment not finding the deploy.cmd file?
Or are the deployment files imporperly configured?

Any pointers on how to go about solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description & error information, per my experience, I think this issue might be caused by some required python packages in the `requirements.txt` which not be directly supported on Azure App Service, that the reason as below.

> Some packages may not install using pip when run on Azure. It may simply be that the package is not available on the Python Package Index. It could be that a compiler is required (a compiler is not available on the machine running the web app in Azure App Service).

Please see the details about [Troubleshooting - Package Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure#troubleshooting---package-installation) to know how to resolve it manually.

Meanwhile, I discovered another possible issue of yours. The `web.2.7.config` file is a `web.config` template file for Python 2.7. If your project didn't include the `web.config` file, please copy `web.2.7.config` and rename `web.config`, then follow the section [`Web.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure#webconfig) of the same document above to check & configure the deployment to make it works.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I implemented the wheelhouse fix but still came up  with the same error. I'm confused by the content of the web.config file. Should it contain the code as in the Microsoft blog post mentioned above or something like [https://github.com/tzangms/django-azure-template/blob/master/web.config]

Comment: @Bchadwick Did you remove these package names which need to require compiler with installing in the `requirements.txt`, and add the wheel files for these package built by yourself in the `requirements.txt`?

Comment: @Bchadwick I just doubt whether there is a `web.config` file in your project. If it exists, please ignore my suggestion for `web.config`.

Comment: I used `pip wheel --wheel-dir=/wheelhouse -r requirements.txt` to generate a wheelhouse folder then included --find-links wheelhouse in the top of the `requirements.txt` file. Is that the correct method??